# How to manage editing and publication of content

Tags: workflows, nodes

The scenario is this:

1. Content is created or edited:

At that point, the content should be marked or moved to a state of "edited" If the content is new, it should not be published. 
If it is an existing node, it the **ORIGINAL** version should **REMAIN** published until it is "approved".

2. Content is approved:

If the approved node is preexisting, the edited version replaces the old version. 
Otherwise, it is new content and it is moved from not published to published.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to accomplish this. My hope was to use the module *Workflow* and integrate it with *Triggers*.

So far, I'm not seeing an obvious path to making this work as described above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [Workbench Moderation](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation) module.  From the project page:

> Workbench Moderation adds arbitrary moderation states to Drupal core's "unpublished" and "published" node states, and affects the behavior of node revisions when nodes are published. Moderation states are tracked per-revision; rather than moderating nodes, Workbench Moderation moderates revisions.

Comment: I suspected that may be the route... Will Workbench allow a "Published" node to be edited, and upon edit, allow the original Published state to remain Published (publicly visible) - then upon "Approval" of the edited content, replace the old published content with the new approved content?  Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: Have a look at the first page of the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/workbench_moderation): `Once a node is published, its current revision is always the published version. Workbench Moderation changes this; it allows you to use an older revision of a node as the published version, while continuing to edit a newer draft.`

Comment: Oh and note that Workbench Moderation is an addon to Workbench, you'll need both modules I think.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking of. +1 Workbench Moderation module

Answer (score 3):

You can also try the [Revisioning module](https://www.drupal.org/project/revisioning) which describes itself:

> ... for the configuration of workflows to create, moderate and publish
>   content revisions. You use it in scenario's like this:
>
> Authors write content that prior to being made publicly visible must
>   be reviewed (and possibly edited) by moderators. Once the moderators
>   have published the content, authors should be prevented from modifying
>   it while “live”, but they should be able to submit new revisions to
>   their moderators.